# Loadlibrary always return NULL

Tags: c, winapi, visual-c++, loadlibrary

`HINSTANCE hinstLib=LoadLibrary("C:\\mydll.dll");`

I have no idea why I always get `0` in return after running that line of code.

Actually I have also another COM dll namely `mydllCOM.dll` that I already registered successfully with `regsvr32` command. I would like to use the above `(mydll.dll)` in my application but always fail at the line as mentioned.

The error code I got from `GetLastError is 193` and I have no idea, why it is about the wrong type of dll

Comment: what is the GetLastError value ?

Comment: Are you on 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: `193` is `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT`. Are you trying to load a 32-bit library into a 64-bit executable, or the other way around?

Comment: It is almost certainly due to what @FrédéricHamidi said

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi ;) yes, excellent!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error code looks like it has the "wrong bitness", meaning you're probably mixing 32-bit and 64-bit executables/DLLs. The setting in the Project properties "Linker->Advanced->Target Machine" should be set to the same value in your DLL and in the executable loading that DLL.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem but with a dll that wasn't mine.
The solution was to change the Character set(i.e. Project properties->configuration Properties->general->Character set).
The default was unicode and when I changed it to multi-Byte i managed to load the dll.

Answer (score 1):

You can't load 32bit DLLs into 64bit applications and vice versa.

You need to recompile your `Application` and `Dll` with the same `Linker->Advanced->Target Machine` setting.

Comment: as Frederic stated it is only for managed languages/code. as for visual studio it targets by default x86 code